# React: Child Components Without JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create `React` components and add child components to it without the use of `JSX`. I tried the following:

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const template = Object.assign({}, this.state, this.props);
    return React.createElement("p", {}, "hello world");
  }
}

class Component  extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const template = Object.assign({}, this.state, this.props);
    return React.createElement("div", {}, ChildComponent);
  }
}
```

I also tried this

```
const childComponent = createReactClass({
  render: function() {
    const template = Object.assign({}, this.state, this.props);
    return React.createElement("p", {}, "hello world");
  }
});

const component = createReactClass({
  render: function() {
    const template = Object.assign({}, this.state, this.props);
    return React.createElement("div", {}, childComponent);
  }
});
```

And I get this error:

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or
>   maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Comment: I think your classes (first snippet) still need to extend `React.Component`.

Comment: Try to add as a Child `React.createElement(childComponent)`

Comment: @MateiRadu sorr that was a copy paste error. fixed the posr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do to create element is to pass the third parameter as the React element instead of a normal argument. Make use of React.createElement to create an element out of the react ChildComonent class

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const template = Object.assign({}, this.state, this.props);
    return React.createElement("p", {}, "hello world");
  }
}

class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const template = Object.assign({}, this.state, this.props);
    return React.createElement("div", {}, React.createElement(ChildComponent));
  }
}
```

[**Working codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/n3lmmlqk7l)